# Looking for dimensional analysis practice

Tags: dimensional-analysis, education, specific-reference

I just finished Bridgman's book on dimensional analysis, and am trying to work through the problems. Does anyone know of an answer key for Bridgman's book?

Here is the book in question:

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dimensional_Analysis/ApTQAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

The link the moderator provided indicates that this topic is indeed relevant to the forum, as it concerns mathematics as it applies to physics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as outside the scope of res. recom. qs.